# wxpython: How can I open a new frame from the main program when pushing a button

Tags: popup, wxpython, call, frame

I have a GUI using wxpython. My main program has several Tabs. in one of these Tabs i added a button, when this button is clicked, a new window should pop-up where some code is happening and once the user has finished and pushes the DONE button it will return to the main program and continue with the main code. I want the user to be able to copy files from one directory to another directory using the pop-up window. Once he has all the necessary files copied, the calculation will continue.

My pop-up program runs fine stand-alone, however I don't know how I can call it from the main program... I import the test.py file in my main program but how do I initiate? I tried with test.pop_up() but then I cannot close the pop-up frame anymore but only get an error message (frame2 is not defined).This is my test.py code which I wanted to call from the main frame so it is showing up as a pop-up window.

```
import wx
import os
import sys
import shutil

class LeftPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)

        label = "Buttons" 
        lbl = wx.StaticText(self, label=label)

        self.attach_btn = wx.Button(self, -1, "Select",size = (150,25))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnOpen, self.attach_btn)

        self.remove_btn = wx.Button(self, -1, "Remove")
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnRemove, self.remove_btn)

        v_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(v_sizer, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        sizer.Add(lbl, 0, wx.ALL|wx.CENTER, 5)
        sizer.Add(self.attach_btn,0, wx.ALL |wx.EXPAND , 3)
        sizer.Add(self.remove_btn,0, wx.ALL |wx.EXPAND, 3)

        self.SetSizer(sizer)

    def OnOpen(self, event):
        print('do something')


    def OnRemove(self,event):
        print('do something else')

class MainPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)

        hsizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        v_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        left_panel = LeftPanel(self)
        hsizer.Add(left_panel,1,wx.EXPAND)

        self.done_btn = wx.Button(self, -1, "DONE")
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnDone, self.done_btn)        

        v_sizer.Add(hsizer, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        v_sizer.Add(self.done_btn,0, wx.ALL |wx.CENTER, 3)

        self.SetSizer(v_sizer)

    def OnDone(self,event):
        self.Destroy()
        wx.CallAfter(frame2.Destroy)

class NewFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title="Costing Selection")
        panel = MainPanel(self)
        self.Show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame2 = NewFrame()
    frame2.SetWindowStyle(wx.STAY_ON_TOP)
    app.MainLoop()

def pop_up():
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame2 = NewFrame()
    frame2.SetWindowStyle(wx.STAY_ON_TOP)
    app.MainLoop()
```

I am not sure about the bottom of my program. Do I need the def pop_up()? I don't know how else I can call the function...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple example.
This is your main calling program, which calls the popup

```
import wx
from Test import NewFrame

class TopFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title="Test")
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.call_button = wx.Button(self.panel, label="Call Popup")
        self.call_button.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.popup)
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(self.panel)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)
        self.Show()

    def popup(self, event):
        pop = NewFrame()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App()
    frame2 = TopFrame()
    app.MainLoop()
```

and here is your popup code in Test.py:

```
import wx
import os
import sys
import shutil

class LeftPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)

        label = "Buttons"
        lbl = wx.StaticText(self, label=label)

        self.attach_btn = wx.Button(self, -1, "Select",size = (150,25))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnOpen, self.attach_btn)

        self.remove_btn = wx.Button(self, -1, "Remove")
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnRemove, self.remove_btn)

        v_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(v_sizer, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        sizer.Add(lbl, 0, wx.ALL|wx.CENTER, 5)
        sizer.Add(self.attach_btn,0, wx.ALL |wx.EXPAND , 3)
        sizer.Add(self.remove_btn,0, wx.ALL |wx.EXPAND, 3)

        self.SetSizer(sizer)

    def OnOpen(self, event):
        print('do something')


    def OnRemove(self,event):
        print('do something else')

class MainPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)

        hsizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        v_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        left_panel = LeftPanel(self)
        hsizer.Add(left_panel,1,wx.EXPAND)

        self.done_btn = wx.Button(self, -1, "DONE")
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnDone, self.done_btn)

        v_sizer.Add(hsizer, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        v_sizer.Add(self.done_btn,0, wx.ALL |wx.CENTER, 3)

        self.SetSizer(v_sizer)

    def OnDone(self,event):
        self.Close()
        self.Parent.Destroy()

class NewFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title="Costing Selection")
        panel = MainPanel(self)
        self.SetWindowStyle(wx.STAY_ON_TOP)
        self.Show()
```

The only real difference is the `OnDone` function, which because of the way the code is written, needs to `Close` self and `Destroy` the parent. Otherwise we would destroy `MainPanel` but leave it's parent `NewFrame` in place.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot Rolf, this helped me a lot and I was now able to finish my program in the way I wanted.